# Why is a transform not available after waitForTransform?

Tags: ros, laser-geometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ros-users,

I have strange issue with tf-transforms. I use laser_geometry::LaserProjection to project laser scans to point clouds, but I assume the problem is related to tf. The code-snippet is from the scan callback function.

```
if(!gTfListener->waitForTransform(scan->header.frame_id,
                              "camera",
                              scan->header.stamp,
                              ros::Duration(2.0),
                              ros::Duration(0.01),
                              &error_msg))
{
    ROS_WARN("Warning 1: %s", error_msg.c_str());
    return;
}
try
{
    gProjector->transformLaserScanToPointCloud("camera", *scan, cloud, *gTfListener);
}catch(tf::TransformException e)
{
    ROS_WARN("Warning 2: %s", e.what());
    return;
}
```

After a few seconds of running, Warning 2 is raised on the console for like 1 out of 4 scans with this error message:

> Warning 2: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1412757571.359567610 but the latest data is at time 1412757571.357117891, when looking up transform from frame [laser_link] to frame [camera]

How can this happen, after waitForTransform obviously succeeded (returned true)?

Thanks in advance,
Sebastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194462/why-is-a-transform-not-available-after-waitfortransform?/) by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1658 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) on 2014-10-08**:
you could try to set a very long time for the duration (the time it should wait) . My computer was slow and it solved the problem

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2014-10-08**:
Increasing the wait time did not change the behaviour, as waitForTransform already returned true (e.g. didn't timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My assumption about tf was wrong, the solution was indeed related to laser_geometry. As described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry), the Projector uses start and end time of the scan and therefore asks for a timestamp in the future.

So to wait long enough, the call to waitForTransform should be:

```
if(!gTfListener->waitForTransform(
       scan->header.frame_id,
       "camera",
        scan->header.stamp + ros::Duration().fromSec(scan->ranges.size()*scan->time_increment),
        ros::Duration(2.0),
        ros::Duration(0.01),
        &error_msg))
```

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2